# Installing Root using Linux Subsystem on Windows: "error: no member named 'fgetws' in the global namespace"

Tags: root

I am trying to install ROOT (6.10.08) on a Linux Subsystem on Windows (Ubuntu 16.04). More details are described [here](https://root.cern.ch/building-root). When I try to build root (cmake --build .), 69% through the build, I run into the following problem:

```
[ 69%] Generating G__ODBC.cxx, ../../lib/libRODBC_rdict.pcm, ../../lib/libRODBC.rootmap
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:40:
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:143:11: error: no member named 'fgetws' in the global namespace
  using ::fgetws;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:145:11: error: no member named 'fputws' in the global namespace
  using ::fputws;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:149:11: error: no member named 'getwc' in the global namespace
  using ::getwc;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:150:11: error: no member named 'getwchar' in the global namespace
  using ::getwchar;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:155:11: error: no member named 'putwc' in the global namespace
  using ::putwc;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:156:11: error: no member named 'putwchar' in the global namespace
  using ::putwchar;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:158:11: error: no member named 'swprintf' in the global namespace
  using ::swprintf;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:167:11: error: no member named 'vswprintf' in the global namespace
  using ::vswprintf;
        ~~^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:43:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/localefwd.h:40:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++locale.h:52:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uselocale'
  extern "C" __typeof(uselocale) __uselocale;
                      ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++locale.h:62:11: error: unknown type name '__locale_t'
  typedef __locale_t            __c_locale;
          ^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:43:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/localefwd.h:42:
/usr/include/c++/5/cctype:87:11: error: no member named 'isblank' in the global namespace
  using ::isblank;
        ~~^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/atomicity.h:35:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr.h:148:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr-default.h:35:
In file included from /mnt/c/MinGW/include/pthread.h:76:
/mnt/c/MinGW/include/_ptw32.h:55:4: error: "Please upgrade your GNU compiler to one that supports __declspec."
#  error "Please upgrade your GNU compiler to one that supports __declspec."
   ^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/atomicity.h:35:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr.h:148:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr-default.h:35:
In file included from /mnt/c/MinGW/include/pthread.h:179:
/mnt/c/MinGW/include/time.h:383:1: error: unknown type name '__MINGW_IMPORT'
__MINGW_IMPORT char     *tzname[2];
^
/mnt/c/MinGW/include/time.h:383:16: error: expected unqualified-id
__MINGW_IMPORT char     *tzname[2];
               ^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5249:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/string_conversions.h:41:
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:126:11: error: no member named 'at_quick_exit' in the global namespace
  using ::at_quick_exit;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:149:11: error: no member named 'quick_exit' in the global namespace
  using ::quick_exit;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:241:11: error: no member named 'atoll' in the global namespace
  using ::atoll;
        ~~^
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdlib:262:22: error: no member named 'atoll' in namespace '__gnu_cxx'
  using ::__gnu_cxx::atoll;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from input_line_2:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:5402:51: error: no member named 'vswprintf' in namespace 'std'
  { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<wstring>(&std::vswprintf, 4 * sizeof(int),
                                             ~~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

 *** Break *** segmentation violation
```

I'm a beginner and am following the steps as closely as I can. I was wondering if anyone could offer advice as to the errors I am running into, and potential fixes.

Thanks!